# Python Pandas: DataFrame converter coluna de Timestamp para DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timestamp

Como posso converter uma coluna DataFrame de Timestamp para DateTime?

```
btc_df = pd.DataFrame ( bars_day , columns=['date' , 'volume' , 'open' , 'high' , 'low' , 'close'] )
```

Sumário

```
date       int64
volume    object
open      object
high      object
low       object
close     object
dtype: object
                 volume      open  ...
date                               ...                          
1610323200000  38150.02  38264.74  ...
1610409600000  35410.37  36628.00  ...
1610496000000  34049.15  37850.00  ...
1610582400000  37371.38  40100.00  ...
1610668800000  39145.21  39747.76  ...
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [1610323200000,1610409600000,1610409600000,1610496000000,1610582400000]
volume = [38150.02,35410.37,34049.15,37371.38,39145.21]
abertura = [38264.74,36628.00,37850.00,40100.00,39747.76]
```

Você pode utilizar o astype e passar datetime como parametro

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64[ms]')
```

Saída

```
          Date    Volume        Open
0   2021-01-11  38150.02    38264.74
1   2021-01-12  35410.37    36628.00
2   2021-01-12  34049.15    37850.00
3   2021-01-13  37371.38    40100.00
4   2021-01-14  39145.21    39747.76
```

Comment: Obrigado, pela resposta porem como posso obter a data + hora? Alguma recomendação?

Comment: @LEANDROFIGUEIRA, boa tarde! Pode utilizar o `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`. Abraço!

Comment: Isto que não estou conseguindo compreender:
'''
btc_df['date'] = btc_df['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]') 
1970-01-01 00:26:50.323200 
btc_df['date'] = btc_df['date'].astype('datetime64[ms]')
2021-01-11 
btc_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(btc_df['date'])
1970-01-01 00:26:50.323200
'''
Não tem como retornar no mesmo objeto data+hora?

Comment: @LEANDROFIGUEIRA Sua hora é um conjunto de zeros, por isso o pandas 'elimina' a hora. Caso você coloque por exemplo 1 no ultimo número ele irá te retornar a data e a hora(faça um teste). Com as data que você tem ai você tem que trata-las como ms, como ns você precisaria ter mais números no seu timestamp. Abraço!